# Why not encrypt the Java bytecode instead of obfuscate it?

Tags: java, cryptography, jvm, obfuscation, decompiling

Looking at the of effort some oragnizations do to obfuscate Java bytecode to avoid others to decompile it and extract secret information from the code, taking in account the limitations of this practice):

Wouldn't it be feasible to use asymmetric encryption to face this problem? I mean, wouldn't it be possible for Oracle to equip the JVM with a certificate and a ClassLoader capable of decrypt encrypted class files using the private key of this certificate?

Of course, the classes would have been encrypted **using the public key of this "unique oracle certificate"**.

The private key would be inside the JVM.

I suppose that maybe it is not mathematically possible to protect this private key inside the JVM (encrypting it in turn...), and that it would be eventually hacked... is this the case???

Comment: It's kind of like DVD or Blu-Ray encryption - it doesn't last very long ;).

Comment: It is in general impossible to secure anything when the attacker is also the receiver (or has full control over the receiver and all his secrets). At best, you can only delay a determined attacker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose that maybe it is not mathematically possible to protect this private key inside the JVM (encrypting it in turn...), and that it would be eventually hacked... is this the case???

Essentially, yes.

If you use symmetric algorithms and store the key in the JVM, it will be trivial to reverse engineer and find those. If you employ obfuscation to hide them, it becomes less trivial, but it can still be done.

With public key crypto, the key doing the decrypting needs to be stored somewhere again. This is essentially a key storage problem and the only difficult to reverse engineer problems are in hardware; even then, they get broken.

[My answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/are-there-drm-techniques-to-effectively-prevent-pirating/4639#4639) on IT security concerning effective DRM protection methods covers this in a little more detail.

Answer (score 6):

If the private key is inside the **JVM** it will take literally minutes to hackers and crackers to get what that key is using reverse engineering.

Besides, classloader will probably be very slow if it has to use asymmetric encryption every time it needs to load a class.

Comment: Yes, but I have seen a company where encryption key were sent to `ClassLoader` (by a HTTPS query) which could then decrypt class files (sent through a different HTTPS connection using an URIClassLoader). Even if it is feasible technically, it has important drawbacks, like multiple points of failures.

Comment: Yes. That's true and definitely interesting. But it will make the classloader reaaaally slow. I guess it could be useful for certain scenarios where you really, really, really need to protect a Class' content.

Comment: Well, for the efficiency issue, the strategy could be to use ASYMMETRIC approach to encrypt a SYMMETRIC key, and encrypt the code with this symmetric key. Then the ClassLoader would efficiently decrypt this simmetric key, and use it (the same way https works). For the reverse engineering of the JVM to get the private key... i will wait a bit just in case somebody shows up with a possible strategy to avoid this hacking, making this approach feasible.

Comment: @edutesoy: symmetric encryption is definitely faster than asymmetric. **But**, it's still orders of magnitude slower than just opening and loading an unencrypted class. Let's say you use this technique to encrypt Eclipse plugins. It will probably take four or five times the time it takes now to launch the venerable IDE...

Comment: "@Pablo Santa Cruz" yes, but you do it only **once**, on de class loading... Of course, it would be applicable to concrete cases (not eclipse) and only **sensible classes** would be encrypted (election of the developer, of course).

Answer (score 1):

In any case, it's impossible to protect private certificate at the client machine (e.g. in JVM). How do you imagine it? If it was a plain text file, obviously it could be extracted. If it was encrypted, the "second level" key would have to be on client machine as well so that JVM could use the private cert for code protection. So you would be able to extract that key, and consequently the private cert, as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the signing scheme to be hard to break, the key needs to be inaccessible.

If you have the complete program this is not hard to extract for a programmer.  Any platform which can actually do this, has the key outside of reach for programmers.

You might find this story about getting the private key from an Airport Express interesting: http://mafipulation.org/blagoblig/2011/04/08#shairport

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the oracle JVM isn't the only JVM around. every JVM must adhere to a standard (Java Virtual Machine Specification) to ensure a very basic principle of java: "write once, run anywhere". a private key like this would cause the oracle jvm to behave differently than all other implementations

Answer (score 1):

If code is encrypted it must be decrypted at some point. It is a simple tautology. Obfuscation however is in many cases irreversible.